# Optimize data mobile on Android

Tags: android, optimization, 3g-network

I have a radio station who's streaming from shoutcast and I can't make it play on data mobile. So the problem is not the media player is the optimization of the 3G network. I google it but I didn't found any documentation from where to start. Thank you.

Comment: By "optimize" you mean increase the throughput so the music stream plays smoothly?

Comment: On Wifi is working perfect but on 3G network is not even starting.

Comment: Visit a speed test website on the mobile and see if you have some kind of connection (I think 20kB/s is enough for a music stream). There is most likely nothing you can do besides complaining to your provider.

Comment: The 3G is loading websites and is running fine on other similar application with the same radio channel. And on Wifi my app is starting the streaming in 6-7 seconds and the other app is starts in maximum 3 seconds.

Comment: Well.. you are doing something wrong or not as good as the other app. Try to find out what using a debugger and the DDMS method profiling and the network profiling